# Associating different breeds through turtle attributes

Tags: netlogo

Say I have two classes of turtles, cars and insurers.  There are 5000 cars and 100 insurers.  Initially, cars are assigned a random insurer 1 through 100.  Cars and insurers have several attributes:

```
cars-own [make model age insurance capacity]
insurers-own [number-of-customers minimum-premium maximum-premium average-premium]
```

What I want to do is count the number of cars with insurance = x and assign that value to number-of-customers for insurer x.  For example, if there fourteen cars with insurer 24, I want number-of-customers for insurer 24 to take the value 14.

This seems like it should be straightforward, but since I'm operating between two agentsets I'm having difficulty implementing.  Help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

EDIT:  Additionally, is there a way to generalize this to a links breed?  For example, a road network consists of directed links between nodes.  I want to count the number of cars on any given link:

```
breed [cars car]
breed [insurers insurer]
breed [road_nodes road_node]
directed-link-breed [road_segments road_segment]

cars-own [make model age insurance capacity current-road-segment]
insurers-own [number-of-customers minimum-premium maximum-premium average-premium]    
road-segments-own [number-cars-here]
```

As in the cars/insurers case, I'd like the value of number-cars-here for road_segment x y to be number of cars with current-road-segment = "road_segment x y".

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but directed links seem an obvious way. Unless you will otherwise compute the same number over and over, do not keep a `number-of-customers` attribute.  Just make one directed link from each customer to its insurer, and then count the insurer's in-links whenever you want `number-of-customers`.

Comment: Hi Alan:  Thanks for your suggestion.  Please see my edit above.

Comment: Your edits substantially transform your question.  You should move the road parts into a new question.  As for the rest of the edit, I am uncertain what you are asking, but iiuc the answer is to just add a separate `directed-link-breed [policies policy]` to handle your insurance relationship.

Comment: Alan: your response did answer the insurance policy question, and is much more elegant than what I was considering, thank you.  I was under the impression that a similar methodology could be applied to the cars/links issue; I did not realize that the two were drastically different.  I've gone ahead and posted it as a separate question.